# Explain this CRC16 checksum function

Tags: checksum, crc16

I have a  function for CRC16 checksum on a 255 bytes of data.

The checksum is calculated from the 1st byte until the third last byte. 
Can you please tell what is happening in these codes, specially the "ekmCheckCrc" function?
below is the functions I got.

```
public void tryMe(byte[] responseFromDevice)
{
            byte[] c = new byte[2];
            c[0] = a[253];
            c[1] = a[254];

            log("EKM CRC : " + Integer.toHexString(ekmCheckCrc(responseFromDevice)) +
            " Device CRC : " + Integer.toHexString((int) (c[0])) + Integer.toHexString((int) (c[1])) );
}

    public int ekmCheckCrc(byte[] dat) {
        int crc = 0xffff;

        for (int i = 1; i < dat.length-3; i++) {
            crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ ekmCrcLut[(crc ^  dat[i]) & 0xff];
        }

       crc = (crc >>> 8) | (crc << 8);
       crc = crc & 0x7f7f;

        return crc;
    }

    static int[] ekmCrcLut = new int[]{
        0x0000, 0xc0c1, 0xc181, 0x0140, 0xc301, 0x03c0, 0x0280, 0xc241,
                       (EKM's LUT sits here, no point including the rest of it)
        0x8201, 0x42c0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81c1, 0x8081, 0x4040
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `a` is the same as `responseFromDevice`, it's calculating some sort of hash function for the message (minus the first byte and the last three bytes), and then printing it out, plus a number (checksum) found at the end of the message. The bytes it's skipping are the device's checksum and presumably some framing bytes. A real implementation would presumably compare the calculated hash to the hash found in the message to verify that it's intact.

If you really want to know how hash functions work, you'll have to read into the subject quite a bit, but if you want a peripheral description on what they do and what they're good for, read [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Comment: alright but what does this code do:

for (int i = 1; i < dat.length-3; i++) {
            crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ ekmCrcLut[(crc ^  dat[i]) & 0xff];
        }

Comment: @Fazel: It's part of the hash calculation. I'm not going to explain you how basic arithmetic works - read a tutorial on Java operators or something